# Diffie-Hellman Application

Tags: diffie-hellman

Alice and Bob want to perform a Diffie-Hellman key exchange using the group $G$, a
primitive root $g$, Alice’s secret key $k_A$ and Bob’s secret key $k_B$. In each case below
compute the element of $G$ that Alice sends to Bob, the element that Bob sends to
Alice, and the secret key that Alice and Bob will share.

1. $G=\mathbb Z/163\mathbb Z$(as an additive group), $g = 2$, $k_A = 128$, $k_B = 65$.
2. $G=\mathbb F_{163}^*$, $g = 2$, $k_A = 128$, $k_B = 65$
3. $G = [0, 1) ∩ \mathbb Q$ with group operation
   $$a\Diamond b = [a + b] = a + b − \left \lceil{a+b}\right \rceil$$
   $g = 23/123$, $k_A = 358$ and $k_B = −44$.
4. $G = GL_2(\mathbb F_{17})$, $g= \left[\begin{array}{ c c }
        2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5
     \end{array} \right]$, $k_A = 13$, $k_B = 5$.

For $1)$  I did the following, Alice sends Bob $A = (128)2 \bmod p$ and then Bob sends Alice $B = (65)2 \bmod p$. Their secret key is $(128+65)2 \bmod p$.

For $2)$ I did this: Alice sends Bob $A = 2^{128}$ $mod p$ and Bob sends Alice $B = 2^{65} \bmod p$ Therefore, their secret key is $B = 2^{(65)(128)} \bmod p$.

For $3)$ Alice sends Bob $128\Diamond 23/123$ and Bob sends Alice $65\Diamond 23/123$ so their secret key is $(128\Diamond 65)\Diamond 23/123$. However I don't know whether this is right or not.

I don't know how to do the fourth one.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have (3) correct; Alice sends Bob $116/123$, Bob sends Alice $95/123$, and their secret key is $62/123$.  How did I get that?  Well, consider the group operation, and if $a=p/q$, what is $a\Diamond a\Diamond ... \Diamond a$

Comment: The ceiling function makes any fraction in it as the highest integer. So Alice sends Bob $358+23/123 - \left \lceil{358+23/123}\right \rceil=358+23/123 - 359$ which is not the same as you provided.

Comment: No, Alice does not send $358\diamond 23/123$ (for one, $358$ is not a member of the group $G$); instead, she sends $23/123\ \diamond\ 23/123\ \diamond\ 23/123\ \diamond ... \diamond\ 23/123$

Comment: $23/123\diamond 23/123$ is $46/123 - 1$ ?

Comment: Never mind I got it. $23/123$ multiplied $358$ times mod $123 = 116/123$ Although i don't understand why it's mod 123

Comment: About notation: Why use $p$ for 1 and 2, if you are given  concrete numbers? In the third example: The expression "mod" is entirely wrong here. The structure is continuous, not integer. More formally: It is not a finite group, possibly not even a group at all. In a general way of looking things: Both sides have an integer *exponent/multiplier* as secret key, which gives you the number of times, which the basic operation is applied to the generator with itself. The rest is just basic math (for no. 4 as well)

Comment: I believe that one thing that might be confusing you about (3) is that it appears that the group operation is typo'ed; I believe it should be $a + b - \left \lfloor{a+b}\right \rfloor$; as written, that operation generally doesn't produce a group member (a rational between 0 and 1); with my correction, it does form a group (albeit not a finite one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eve shouldn't be able to find the shared secret easily from the messages Alice and Bob send.

In the questions 1 and 2, you said that the shared secret is the sum/the product of the two messages, but anyone can compute them. Therefore, you are wrong.
The shared secret should be: 
1) $B=(128)(65)2 = (65)(128)2\mod p$, 
2) $B=(2^{(65)})^{(128)}=(2^{(128)})^{(65)}\mod p$.

Once you understood these two examples, I am sure you will be able to solve the 2 other questions easily by thinking a bit more about it.

Edit: you're right about 2).

Comment: But for the second one, $2^{(65)^{(128)}} = 2^{(65)(128)}$. What confuses me about 3 is the primitive root $g$. I can't think of a way to express it other than what i came up with.

Comment: There was no question about *security* or Eve. This is a purely "try to figure out how DH works in toy examples" homework. And it shows quite easily in 1) why the dlog problem is required to be hard, if the DH problem should be hard to solve.

Comment: wWhat I meant is that even if you can't solve dlog in an additive group (which is super easy), you could break the scheme.
For the first one, Eve can still find the shared secret but not as easily because she needs to compute a dlog... I'm not sure about whether this makes sense or not.